# custom dropdown menu doesn't close on click and other multiple issues

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hi guys i have an issue with our dropdown menu nested inside an accordion.
please note that the menu is visible in small displays such as phones.

now what the dropdown does is when you click it, it fires perfectly, but it pushes other links beside it, secondly the drop down doesnt close when you click on a different area of the page, and lastly when a dropdown is active, then click a different dropdown link it automatically goes to the first link within that dropdown

here is the html:

```
<div id="accordion" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 hidden-md hidden-lg">
<div class="accordion-toggle text-center">
    <div class="bars"></div>
    <div class="bars"></div>
    <div class="bars"></div>
</div>
<div class="accordion-content test_dd_fix">
    <ul class="list-inline">
        <volist name="category_tree" id="vo1">  
            <li class="nav_li">
                <a <if condition="$vo1[id]==43 || $vo1[id]==22">
                    style="color:red"
                    <else /></if>class="" href="{:U('Goods/index?category_id='.$vo1['id'])}">{$vo1.title}
                </a>
                <notempty name="vo1._child">
                <div class="nav_erji">
                    <div class="nav_erji_dropdown" >
                            <volist name="vo1._child" id="vo2">
                                <div class="nav_erji_div">
                                    <h4><a href="{:U('Goods/index?category_id='.$vo2['id'])}">{$vo2.title}</a></h4>
                                    <notempty name="vo2._child">
                                        <ul class="list-inline">
                                            <volist name="vo2._child" id="vo3">
                                                <li><a href="{:U('Goods/index?category_id='.$vo3['id'])}">{$vo3.title}</a></li>
                                            </volist>
                                        </ul>
                                    </notempty>
                                </div>
                            </volist>
                        <div>
                        <volist name="category_adv" id="vo">
                            <switch name="vo.target_type">
                                <case value="1">
                                    <a class="font_shift" href="{$vo.target_data}" target="_blank">
                                        <div class="nav_ad_pic"><img src="{$vo.cover_pc}"/></div>
                                        <h2>{$vo.title}</h2>
                                    </a>
                                </case>
                                <case value="2">
                                    <a href="{:U('Goods/detail?id='.$vo['target_data'])}" target="_blank">
                                        <div class="nav_ad_pic"><img src="{$vo.cover_pc}"/></div>
                                        <h2>{$vo.title}</h2>
                                    </a>
                                </case>
                                <case value="3">
                                    <a href="{:U('Goods/index?category_id='.$vo['target_data'])}" target="_blank">
                                        <div class="nav_ad_pic"><img src="{$vo.cover_pc}"/></div>
                                        <h2>{$vo.title}</h2>
                                    </a>
                                </case>
                                <case value="4">
                                    <a href="{:U('Article/detail?id='.$vo['target_data'])}" target="_blank">
                                        <div class="nav_ad_pic"><img src="{$vo.cover_pc}"/></div>
                                        <h2>{$vo.title}</h2>
                                    </a>
                                </case>
                            </switch>
                        </volist>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </notempty>
        </li>
        </volist>
    </ul>

    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="{:U('Goods/brands')}" class="nav_1">Shop By Brands</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

and this is the css:

```
.nav_erji_dropdown {background-color:#000; position: absolute !important ;z-index: 1000 !important;}
.nav1{position:relative;background:#fff;}
.nav1 .nav_li{float:left;color:#ffffff;}
.nav1 .nav_li .nav_1{display:block;color:#ffffff;margin-right:30px;height:55px;line-height:55px;font-size:14px;margin-bottom:-2px;}
.nav1 .active .nav_1{border-bottom:2px solid #EDCC27}
.test_dd_fix {overflow: visible !important; }
.nav1_erji{position:relative;top:57px;left:0px;right:0px;background:#fff;display:none;}
.nav1_erji.active {display:block;}
.nav1_erji .wra1{margin:20px auto;}
.nav1_erji_div{float:left;width:240px;padding-right:100px;}
.nav1_erji_div h4{font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;height:30px;line-height:30px;padding-bottom:10px;margin-bottom:10px;}
.nav1 .nav1_li .nav1_erji_div ul li a{height:30px;line-height:30px;border:none;padding:0px;font-size:12px;}
```

so far this is the only javascript i added

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#accordion').find('.accordion-toggle').click(function(){

      //Expand or collapse this panel
      $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');

      //Hide the other panels
      $(".accordion-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');

    });
  });
</script>
```

its a lot of issue but i would really appreciate it if we could fix this together, thanks guys!

Comment: try to add some working fiddle related to your issue

Comment: i'll do my best to add a fiddle @AravindReddy, we're not really familiarized with the whole structure since this was made by another team and we're just updating it. will look for the neccessary codes to make the fiddle work